# How to set some values to NA based on a binary number in R?

Tags: r

I have two datasets `y and x` that I want to filter y based on x.

```
   y=c(0.5,0.2,0.1,0.6,0.4,1.3,0.6,2.8)
   x=c(128,64,32,16,2,48,24,6)
   Package HapEstXXR
   x=dec2bin(x)
   x
           128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
  128   1  0  0  0 0 0 0 0
  64    0  1  0  0 0 0 0 0
  32    0  0  1  0 0 0 0 0
  16    0  0  0  1 0 0 0 0
  2     0  0  0  0 0 0 1 0
  48    0  0  1  1 0 0 0 0
  24    0  0  0  1 1 0 0 0
  6     0  0  0  0 0 1 1 0
```

As you can see the decimal numbers in `x` were converted to binary number. So we have eight numbers. from the left to right bit1 bit2 bit3....bit8.

I need to do this: when `bit2,bit4, and bit8` in `x = 1`, replace the corresponding values in `Y by NA`.

Comment: do you mean bit2, bit4 AND bit8 have to be 1 or bit2, bit4 OR bit8 have to be 1 ? because there is no x value for which bit2, bit4 AND bit8 are 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "second" `x` object is a matrix, you can do:

```
y[rowSums(x[,c(2,4,8)])==3] <- NA
```

If you want to put `NA` in `y` when either bit2, bit4 or bit8 is `1` (contrary to what is above, which put a `NA` when all 3 values are `1`), you can do:

```
y[rowSums(x[,c(2,4,8)])>=1] <- NA
```

Comment: Can you show the output of y as I don't get any values in y replaced by NA with this condition.  May be the example is not corrext

Comment: @akrun, well, this is because there is no x value for which values of bit2, bit4 and bit8 are 1...

Comment: I understand your code, but I thought this is not what the OP wanted

Comment: @akrun, thanks for pointing out, I ask the OP to get a clarification, and I added a code to put NA when either value is 1, just in case ;-)